# Delete row function lead to run time error '-214702882 (8007000e)':

Tags: excel, vba

Hello I have a sheet listed as `ThisWorkBook.Sheets("Dash Board")` or sheet1. That sheet contain a listbox that show data table from sheet2 with name "Data Barang". I tried to create a delete row command button from shape and assigned it with the function at sheet1 where my dash board displayed, but every time I click on, it shows nothing and when I click other assigned button such as update data button (it works perfectly fine before I clicked delete button) it got an error

> run time error '-214702882 (8007000e)': it says not enough memory.

[image]

this is the code that I used on my delete button in module

```
Sub DeleteRow(ByVal row As Long)

   ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data Barang").Range("A2").Offset(row).EntireRow.Delete

End Sub
```

and then I call the function and assign it to my shape
this is the code at sheet1

```
Sub hapus()

    Call DeleteRow(Sheet1.DataBarang.ListIndex)

End Sub
```

can any body help me? my intention is to delete a row that I have selected in the list box that displayed data from table in other sheet (sheet2)

this is the listfillrange of my listbox

```
Sub loaddata()
    
    Dim listdata As Object
    Set listdata = Sheet1.DataBarang ' this is my listbox name in sheet1
    Dim tabeldata As Object
    Set tabeldata = Sheet2.ListObjects("DataBarang") 'this is my data table in sheet 2. it have a same name with my listbox name in sheet1
    
    With listdata
        .AutoLoad = True
        .ColumnHeads = True
        .ColumnCount = 12
        .ListFillRange = tabeldata.DataBodyRange.Address(External:=True)
        
    End With

End Sub
```

and then i recall it in this code

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    Call loaddata
    Call locktextbox

End Sub
```

Comment: Is there a sheet named "Data Barang", or a list box having this name? If a list box, `Sheets("Data Barang").Range("A2")` does not have any meaning for VBA... A list box does not have a `Range` property. I can also see a list box named "DataBarang". Is there a sheet named "Data Barang" having a list box with the name "DataBarang" and code name `Sheet2`?

Comment: What is in the ListFillRange for the ListBox?

Comment: What is `.Offset(row)` doing? I'm not sure I've seen row used in offset like this before, but is Row even defined?

Comment: sorry i just replied today. @FaneDuru yes there is a sheet named "Data Barang" and that sheet contain a listbox named "DataBarang" i'll update my post it with a picture.

Comment: @CDP1802 i edit my post with listfillrange code for my listbox.

Comment: @Brett actually i got it from some videos in youtube and i tried to implement it. but it only work when the listbox in userform and not using table data as a range. the truth is did not even know how how that code works specifically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `ListFillRange` before you delete the row and then re-apply it.

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub btnDelete_Click()
    Dim i As Long
    i = Sheet1.DataBarang.ListIndex
    
    With Sheet2.ListObjects("DataBarang")
        If i >= 0 And .ListRows.Count > 0 Then
            Sheet1.DataBarang.ListFillRange = ""
            .ListRows(i + 1).Delete
            Call loaddata
        End If
    End With
End Sub

Sub loaddata()
    Dim tbl As ListObject, rng As Range
    Set tbl = Sheet2.ListObjects("DataBarang")
    
    With Sheet1.DataBarang ' ListBox
        .AutoLoad = True
        .ColumnHeads = True
        .ColumnCount = 12
         .ListFillRange = ""
        If tbl.ListRows.Count = 0 Then
            Set rng = tbl.Range.Rows(2)
        Else
            Set rng = tbl.DataBodyRange
        End If
        .ListFillRange = rng.Address(external:=True)
    End With
End Sub
```